# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'showMePartially' since it isn't a known property of 'allrecords-app'

Tags: angular

I am trying to display the content of the allrecords-app component conditionally using ngIf when a button on the parent component is click. The parent component is dropdown-app. When i run the program locally, the app is blank and i get this error:
Template parse errors:

> Can't bind to 'showMePartially' since it isn't a known property of
>   'allrecords-app'.

```html
<allrecords-app>
<div *ngIf="showMePartially">
  <h1> this part will be toggled by the parent component button</h1>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-allrecords',
  templateUrl: './allrecords.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./allrecords.component.css']
})
export class AllrecordsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() showMePartially: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<dropdown-app>
<div class="All_Records">
    <button type="button" label="Click" (click)="toggleChild()">Click to display all records</button>
    <div>
        <allrecords-app [showMePartially]="showVar"></allrecords-app>
    </div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DropdownComponent  {
  showVar: boolean = true;

    toggleChild(){
        this.showVar = !this.showVar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong selector for the child component. Fixed!

Comment: lol same:) i am trying to finish a school project. you saved my time thanks:)